# Why is my threading/multiprocessing python script not exiting properly?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, sigint, keyboardinterrupt

I have a server script that I need to be able to shutdown cleanly. While testing the usual `try..except` statements I realized that `Ctrl-C` didn't work the usual way. Normally I'd wrap long running tasks like this

```
try:
    ...
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    #close the script cleanly here
```

so the task could be shutdown cleanly on `Ctrl-C`. I have never ran into any problems with this before, but somehow when I hit `Ctrl-C` when this particular script is running the script just exits without catching the `Ctrl-C`.

The initial version was implemented using `Process` from `multiprocessing`. I rewrote the script using `Thread` from `threading`, but same issue there. I have used `threading` many times before, but I am new to the `multiprocessing` library. Either way, I have never experienced this `Ctrl-C` behavior before.

Normally I have always implemented sentinels etc to close down `Queues` and `Thread` instances in an orderly fashion, but this script just exits without any response.

Last, I tried overriding `signal.SIGINT` as well like this

```
def handler(signal, frame):
    print 'Ctrl+C'

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
...
```

Here `Ctrl+C` was actually caught, but the handler doesn't execute, it never prints anything.

Besides the `threading` / `multiprocessing` aspect, parts of the script contains `C++` `SWIG` objects. I don't know if that has anything to do with it. I am running Python 2.7.2 on OS X Lion.

So, a few questions:

1. What's going on here?
2. How can I debug this?
3. What do I need to learn in order to understand the root cause?

PLEASE NOTE: The internals of the script is proprietary so I can't give code examples. I am however very willing to receive pointers so I could debug this myself. I am experienced enough to be able to figure it out if someone could point me in the right direction.

**EDIT:** I started commenting out imports etc to see what caused the weird behavior, and I narrowed it down to an import of a `C++ SWIG` library. Any ideas why importing a `C++ SWIG` library 'steals' `Ctrl-C`? I am not the author of the guilty library however and my SWIG experience is limited so don't really know where to start...

**EDIT 2:** I just tried the same script on a windows machine, and in Windows 7 the `Ctrl-C` is caught as expected. I'm not really going to bother with the OS X part, the script will be run in an Windows environment anyway.

Comment: It's going to be impossible to tell without knowing what you're doing between `try:` and `except ...:`.  Does the C++ code do anything with signals?  If so anything could happen.

Comment: a [complete minimal example](http://sscce.org/) might help.

Comment: Sorry can't really do that. I added some findings above however. I'm all ears for SWIG opinions and suggestions...

Comment: Did you try without multithreading/processing?

Comment: Yup, it's definitely the import of the C++ SWIG library that causes it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might have to do with the way Python manages threads, signals and C calls.

In short - Ctrl-C cannot interrupt C calls, since the implementation requires that a python thread will handle the signal, and not just any thread, but the **main thread** (often blocked, waiting for other threads).

In fact, long operations can block everything.

Consider this:

```
>>> nums = xrange(100000000)
>>> -1 in nums
False (after  ~ 6.6 seconds)
>>>
```

Now, Try hitting Ctrl-C (uninterruptible!)

```
>>> nums = xrange(100000000)
>>> -1 in nums
^C^C^C   (nothing happens, long pause)
...
KeyboardInterrupt
>>>
```

The reason Ctrl-C doesn't work with threaded programs is that the main thread is often blocked on an uninterruptible thread-join or lock (e.g, any 'wait', 'join' or just a plain empty 'main' thread, which in the background causes python to 'join' on any spawned threads).

Try to insert a simple

```
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

in your main thread.

If you have a long running C function, do signal handling in C-level (May the Force be with you!).

This is largely based on David Beazley's [video](http://blip.tv/carlfk/mindblowing-python-gil-2243379) on the subject.

Comment: That main Python thread to which you refer is controlled by the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) and it comes up a lot in Python multi-threaded instructions. From what I've read, you are better off using multi-processing, which in Python works quite well. Processes are not blocked by the GIL.

Comment: Yup, `multiprocessing` is probably the way to go with regards to GIL issues. Surprisingly easy to work with since it mirrors the `threading` library. That is, until you run into issues like I did. Then no one will hear you scream.

Answer (score 1):

It exits because something else is likely catching the KeyboardInterupt and then raising some other exception, or simply returning None. You should still get a traceback to help debug.  You need to capture the stderr output or run your script with the -i commandline option so you can see traceback.  Also, add another except block to catch all other exceptions.

If you suspect the C++ function call to be catching the CTRL+C try catching it's output.  If the C function is not returning anything then there isn't much you can do except ask the author to add some exception handling, return codes, etc.

```
try:
    #Doing something proprietary  ...
    #catch the function call output
    result = yourCFuncCall()

    #raise an exception if it's not what you expected
    if result is None:
        raise ValueError('Unexpected Result')

except KeyboardInterupt:
    print('Must be a CTRL+C')
    return

except:
    print('Unhandled Exception')
    raise
```

Comment: When I hit Ctrl-C the scripts exits without printing anything to the console. How can I capture tracebacks etc?

Comment: I ran the script with `python -i script.py` but still nothing when I hit `Ctrl-C`. Any other ways to get any more info of what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

how about atexit? 
http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html#module-atexit

Comment: I was really hopeful that atexit would work, but, alas, it didn't.